# Polynomial division and with large divisor

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to implement the QR Code Specification (ISO/IEC 18004:2015) and it contains some polynomial division (to calculate error codes). I'm trying to teach myself polynomial division but am not getting the same answer as the examples in the specification. The specification shows the remainder as being positive.

[image]

But when I work it out through long division, my remainder is negative, and in a different form.

[image]

My working out is below

[image]

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sort of a wild guess:  Are these polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, in which case $x = -x$?

Comment: @B.Goddard I think so. It doesn't state this anywhere but I'm supposed to take the coefficients and construct a binary string (in this case it would be "110010010100"). Do I just ignore the negative sign?

Comment: I think so.  But I don't really know anything about QR codes.

Comment: I'm not going to pay 200 CHF for the spec, but does it mention "Galois field", "finite field", or "characteristic 2" anywhere? That's clearly the root issue, but it's hard to give a definitive answer without a precise description of what the polynomial division is accomplishing, and it seems that QR uses multiple codes (RS and BCH at minimum).

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes it does mention "galois field", I'll have to double check the spc but it's something like the (15, 10). I don;t really know what that means apart from I have to raise the original divisor by the power of 10

Answer (score 1):

$$  \left(   x^{14}  +  x^{13}  +  x^{12}  \right)  =  \left(   x^{12}  +  x^{11}  +  x^{10}  +  x^{9}  +  x^{8}  +  x^{5}  +  x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot   \left(   x^{2}  \right)  +  \left(   -  x^{11}  -  x^{10}  -  x^{7}  -  x^{4}  -  x^{2}  \right)  $$ 
is correct.  For some reason you typed the degree twelve piece in two places.